# Crystal Reports, driving Header/Footer decisions based on a specific detail row

Tags: crystal-reports, global-variables, subreport

I have a simple report that can display many detail rows.
I want to target a specific row and use it's values to populate aspects in the Report Header and Footer.

For example , I know what the minimum(primarykey) within the detail rows that I display.
A simply formula can capture that.

I want to pick up other attributes of the row with the **minimum(primarykey)** and display in the header or footer.

I therefore want to select a specific row select and use its data in the header and footer, something like:
**Select NAME, DATE from DETAILSROWS where DETAIL.PRIMARYKEY = minimum(DETAIL.PRIMARYKEY)**

I've thought about using a subreport here, and passing values back to the main report, but that doesn't see to the way to go... I've tried for example passing **minimum(DETAIL.PRIMARYKEY)** to the subreport so that the sub loads only the row I want, then passing the values back via shared variables.  But I don't want to display the subreport, and if I suppress it, my shared variables don't seem to populate.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying the values in the Report Footer would be easier than the Header. All you'd need to do is compare each row's primary key to the value of `maximum({DETAIL.PRIMARY_KEY})` and save off the values. So something like:

```
stringvar saved_column1;
stringvar saved_column2;

if {DETAIL.PRIMARY_KEY}=maximum({DETAIL.PRIMARY_KEY}) then
 (saved_column1 := {DETAIL.COLUMN1};
 saved_column2 := {DETAIL.COLUMN2})
```

For the header, really the only way I can think of is to use the subreport like you're already doing. I'd just format the subreport to display itself, though, and not mess around with shared variables.

Comment: You are creating this in a formula that you drop into the footer?  Then, how do you access saved_column1 & 2?

Comment: okay - i figured it out by duplicating the variable declariation in yet another formula... however, it really doesn't work very well. MAX seem to work only when the original formula is in the footer... and MIN seems work only when the original formula sits in the header...

Comment: looks like i have to go the subreport route then stick a solid box over the top of it so it won't print /display :(

Comment: @flaZer This formula would need to go in the Details section. You can access the variables in the Report Footer with other formulas that simply spit out the variable value, so like `whileprintingrecords; stringvar saved_column1` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it turns out the SUBREPORT option is the way to go.

SUBREPORT is a bare minimum report that has passed to it, the lookup value you are after.

Long winded, I link to it using a formula that holds essentially: **minimum(DETAIL.PRIMARYKEY)**.

In turn the subreport selects that single detail record.

Within the subreport, build a Formula and drop it the into its report header:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared DateTimeVar subCreationDate := {DETAIL.CREATIONDATE};
Shared StringVar subCreationName := {DETAIL.CREATIONNAME};
```

Finally, suppress all the the sections (delete what u don't need) on the SUBREPORT, and close.

On the main report... Not sure but it looks like the SUBREPORT can sit anywhere.
And because you've suppressed elements WITHIN the SUBREPORT, it won't display on the main report.
(So no need to suppress on the main report - and if you do suppress it there, it won't work anyway!)

Now create your formulas (in my case 2) on the main report and in each, repeat the variable declaration.

```
Shared DateTimeVar subCreationDate
Shared StringVar subCreationName
```

Again, each of the above sit in their individual formula declaration.
And from there, you now have "standard" formulas to work with on your main report.
They can be referenced just like any other!

Thx Ryan - your answer certainly helped me get where I need to go - u still get my +1!